# peer not authenticated about Realm

Tags: android, realm

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download realm-android.jar (io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-android/0.82.1/realm-android-0.82.1.jar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-android/0.82.1/realm-android-0.82.1.jar'.
>   peer not authenticated

I try some solutions in stackoverflow,but still not work 。。。。

Comment: It sounds like a problem with you Gradle/Android studio setup. Possible a wrong proxy setting. Have you tried using that link from a browser?

Comment: @Bruce too, how did you import the realm file? I doubt that you have not added the library properly to `app\libs` folder. If you have added it then I assume that you have added the reference of it in the `dependencies` of `build.gradle` . It should be something like this in the `build.gradle` file
`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
`compile files('libs/realmio.jar')`